# How to display large amounts of data on one page with existing tabs as navigation?

Tags: data, organization

I have a web application that uses the left navigation for major functionality and tabs for displaying different information within a function. One function is to enroll in something. There are several steps, with the last step displaying a summary of your selections before you submit. (All data selected during this process needs to be shown here before you click on the Submit button.) What is the best way to display all data if tabs are already used for the steps? More tabs or using an accordion and showing one or two sections expanded and the other sections collapsed or something else?

Comment: It's difficult to analyze the description of your application' functionality, especially because it can have different interpretations. A visual representation (even simple mock-up) of existing layout would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but making selections in order before submission seams so nineties! This was how the web and ERP:s worked back in the days. You should at each single selection filter results returned accordingly and not have your user play guessing game. Now go back to your development team and tell them they need to be coding for real time, right now!